# Java ServerSocket prevent clients queueing

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, backlog

I am making a sockets program in java, I want to only be able to handle 1 client at a time. I also want to stop a client from from connecting to the socket if another client connected to the server. I know that by default ServerSocket allows for queuing of clients and you can limit the size of the queue by using the

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)
```

constructor. However the Javadoc says that if you set the backlog to 0 it just goes to the default queue length. I can set this to 1 but if i connect 2 clients the second will wait in the queue, and a third will not connect.

Is there anyway to disable this queuing so that a second client that tries to connect simultaneously will be not allowed to connect?

Comment: I think you should be focusing on the `accept` method

Comment: @ScaryWombat I call the accept method to get a client. is there a queue that the accept method reads from and therefore the queue has to be of length at least one?